# What is the relationship Moonbase Alpha to the governments of Earth?

Tags: space-1999

What was the relationship of Alpha to Earth before Breakaway?  It clearly wasn't military, and it didn't seem entirely civilian.  Was is controlled by something like the United Nations?

The series has a few references to a "Space Agency".  I'm finding very few explicit explanations in the episodes.  Can anyone suggest in-universe relatively canon sources for the answer?

Alpha's original purpose seems to have started as scientific research and support center for space exploration.  The series mentions connections to major scientific projects like the Meta probe, the Ultra probe, the Voyager unmanned missions, the Jupiter and Saturn expeditions.  (I'm ignoring that all of these were disasters for this question...)

In the first episode, Commissioner Simmons makes the statement that the current purpose of Alpha was the storage of nuclear waste sent from Earth.  I'm not sure if he is making a emotional point, repeating a mission statement, or bringing up a common belief.  (I'll leave out whether the mission was the "safe" storage of nuclear waste.)

Out-of-universe I understand that the connection to Earth was rarely important to the stories, so it isn't given much description in the series.  Also the ever-changing writing and production staff may have created conflicting statements.

Originally Space:1999 was supposed to be a sequel of sorts to UFO.  That changed early in the pre-production process and I don't see that as canon.  That version of Alpha is the expanded SHADO moonbase and the primary space defense center against the alien invaders.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Space1999.org website](http://www.space1999.org/features/episode_guide/year_one/y1ep1-breakaway.html):

> The **International Lunar Commission** is responsible for Moonbase Alpha, a permanent settlement on Earth's moon, with over 311 inhabitants.

There really isn't much out there beyond this on exactly what the *International Lunar Commission* is, but I took the base to be manned something like what Antarctica is manned today by many different nations, not owned by any.

Wikipedia has it as:

> Though not officially a military installation, Moonbase Alpha has one commanding officer, assigned by the **World Space Commission**, whose function is as administrator and co-ordinator of all operations in the facility.

Whether the ILC and the WSC are the same entities which someone writing a blog has screwed up on, I am unsure.

In this fanzine from 1976 ([Alpha News Letter](http://www.dragonsdomain.co.uk/fanzines/alphanewsletter/alphanewsletter%202.pdf)), the author, Stephen Eramo, talks about Alpha in the Technology section. He says of Alpha:

> Moonbase Alpha is Earth's supreme achievement in 1999. Self-sufficient and fully computerized, the fantastic lunar colony is Earth's global watchdog, silently guarding against sneak alien attack.

It goes on to say:

> The main reasons that Alpha was established was, one, to repel possible alien attacks, and two, since atomic waste has become mans most pressing problem they had to store it somewhere, so they picked the dark side of the moon as a "dump", and Alpha personnel oversee the delivery of it from the Earth.

(NOTE: While a fanzine is possibly not *canon*, it's probably as close as we're going to get. I figure that since it is dated from the time the original series aired from an avid fan of the time, it is about as canon as it gets.)

This same author reprints a section out of a magazine called **Quasimodo Monster Mag - August '75**. It states:

> Space travel near the turn of the century has become commonplace and a vital part of everyday living. A series of routine trips between the Earth and Moon establishes the unquestionable existence of other life forms in space. This fantastic discovery brings all people of the world together in a common effort to protect itself against the potential threat of these other life forms. An early warning-defense system installation, called Moonbase Alpha, is created on the surface of the moon. Alpha is a kind of Outer Space United Nations as it is manned by 311 men and women representing all Earth nations.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't see the newsletter or quasimodo references before.